# objective-c presentViewController position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have thus UIActivityViewConroller like so:

```
- (IBAction)Share:(id)sender {

    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.pdfPath];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];

    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.NavBar;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

My issue is this shows up on the left side of self.NavBar, I would like to position it to the right side, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIPopoverController` with `presentPopoverFromRect`

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:postItems applicationActivities:nil];
UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
[popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Change position of `CGRect` as you want.